# URL Rewriting and PHP code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have made the following `HTAccess` file for my personnal website (which is basically a portfolio).

```
# Error
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?id=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?id=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?id=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?id=500

# Enable URL rewriting
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions Inherit

# Url rewrite for assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gallery(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=302,L]

# Url rewrite for pages
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.+)$ gallery.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^password/(.+)$ password.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^private/(.+)$ private_gallery.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^hidden/(.+)$ hidden_gallery.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^download/(.+)$ download.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
```

This works great when I try to access these URLs directly through my web browser.

In my `HTML` and `PHP` code, I have these *old* URLS. I mean these URLs existed before I wrote the `HTAccess` file.

```
<a href="private_gallery.php?id=SomeGalleryId">Open this gallery</a>
```

When the user clicks on this URL, he is redirected to

```
/private_gallery.php?id=SomeGalleryId
```

and not to

```
/private/SomeGalleryId
```

Is there a way to change that without editing my `PHP`/`HTML` code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another rewrite to match on the query string and do a 301 redirect ... it would probably cause SEO experts to go cross-eyed; better to have the URLs in the form `/private/SomeGalleryId` in your HTML code and redirect invisibly to `private_gallery.php?id=SomeGalleryId` rather than this way around but...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/private_gallery\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\w+).*
RewriteRule ^.*$ /private/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the code if it makes the SEO works better.